# How to get older products from current product ID in Woo commerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get older products in Woocommerce WordPress from the current product id but I don't see any ways to add conditions into an array ( as below). Normally, if I use Mysql query then I will select IDs that have ID < current_ID and order by date (Desc) to get older products (older IDs)

Can anyone support me to edit this code to get older IDs from the current product ID?

```
<?php
global $product;
$product_id=$product->get_id();

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'category' => 15,
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
          wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'older' ); 
endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom queries to get older products of the current product published to date. Try the below code.

```
function get_previous_products( $product_id ){
    global $wpdb;
    $post_date = get_the_date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $product_id );
    $get_all_previous_products = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT p.ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p  WHERE p.post_date > '".$post_date."' AND p.post_type = 'product' ORDER BY p.post_date ASC" );
    $get_all_previous_products = $wpdb->get_col( $get_all_previous_products );
    return $get_all_previous_products;
}

get_previous_products( $product_id );

function get_next_products( $product_id ){
    global $wpdb;
    $post_date = get_the_date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $product_id );
    $get_all_next_products = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT p.ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p  WHERE p.post_date < '".$post_date."' AND p.post_type = 'product' ORDER BY p.post_date ASC" );
    $get_all_next_products = $wpdb->get_col( $get_all_next_products );
    return $get_all_next_products;
}

get_next_products( $product_id );
```

OR you can also use the `date_query` param of `WP_Query`.

```
function get_previous_products( $product_id ){
    $get_all_previous_products = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'before' => get_the_date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $product_id ),
            ),
        ),
        'fields' => 'ids'
    ));

    return $get_all_previous_products->posts;
}

get_previous_products( $product_id );

function get_next_products( $product_id ){
    $get_all_next_products = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'after' => get_the_date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $product_id ),
            ),
        ),
        'fields' => 'ids'
    ));

    return $get_all_next_products->posts;
}

get_next_products( $product_id );
```

Comment: seem you didn't get my question

I mean if I have 9 products like this:

pro 1
pro 2
pro 3
pro 4
pro 5
pro 6
pro 7
pro 8
pro 9

then when I click on product 6 ( pro 6 ) then it will show products on older product block like this:

pro 1
pro 2
pro 3
pro 4
pro 5

and show on newer product block like this:

pro 7
pro 8
pro 9

Comment: Hello Bhautik,
Thanks for your support
Your codes worked a half 

'after' => get_the_date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $product_id ),

did not work, It showed the latest products.

Comment: @iTommy I have updated my answer. please check and let me know if you still facing any issue.